# Como inserir string c# em script CefSharp

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

Como posso inserir uma string c# no script?

```
string teste = "testando";

chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("$(document).ready(function() {alert({0})}); ", teste);
```

Tentei este código mas não retornou nada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O script que você está tentando executar está na sintaxe do jquery, provavelmente a página não vai reconhecer naturalmente isso, então sugiro que você escreva javascript puro pra isso, um exemplo seria fazer assim:

```
script = "document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ alert('qualquer coisa'); });";
```

Ainda assim, caso queira usar jquery, sugiro seguir o código desse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999063/cefsharp-winforms-inject-jquery-into-page).